# Asynchronous YouTube API Calls in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension, youtube-api

I want to get all of my YouTube subscriptions using the YouTube API. However, Google limits the amount of items that get returned in API calls to 50. If I'm subscribed to 100+ channels, I'm going to have to loop the API calls to get all of them. For now I just want to console.log() them in the "Inspect popup" debug console.

I did a lot of reading on how to do async calls in a loop in Javascript, but all of them were with a basic `for()` loop. In the case of using the YouTube Data API, you have to make your API call, then use the `nextPageToken` attribute to get the next page.

This is my `popup.js` file currently:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ClientID = '[my client id]';

    $('#testBtn').click(function() {
        chrome.identity.getAuthToken({"interactive": true}, function(token) {

            GetInfo(token, "");

        });
    });

    function GetInfo(userToken, pageToken) {

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions", 
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                part: "snippet",
                mine: "true",
                nextPageToken: pageToken,
                access_token: userToken
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var allIds = "";
                $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                    console.log(item.snippet.resourceId.channelId);
                });

                var nextPageToken = data.nextPageToken;
                if (typeof nextPageToken !== 'undefined')
                {
                    GetInfo(userToken, nextPageToken);
                }


            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I realize that normally you aren't supposed to make API calls in popup.js, but I just want to get this working then I'll move it to a background script.

This code when executed works great the first time; the success function executes and the channel id's are logged. So I know it's not a problem with authentication. However, when the `GetInfo()` function is called again in the `success` callback, the `data` parameter stays the same. So my script just logs the data in the first callback over and over again indefinitely.

I want to say this is a problem with closures in Javascript, but I don't know what the syntax would look like within an ajax call.

If anyone could help, that would be great!

Comment: And now you have to change that client ID (edit history is preserved). Be careful next time.

Comment: @Xan oops, good catch. I had it blanked out on the initial post, but I edited the code and forgot to change it again. I'll change the client ID immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/pagination), the *parameter* name for the API is `pageToken`, not `nextPageToken`. Your `nextPageToken` param is probably being ignored by the API so you get the first page over and over again. So you should have:

```
        data: {
            part: "snippet",
            mine: "true",
            pageToken: pageToken,
            access_token: userToken
        },
```

Comment: I was typing up an answer to my question right as you posted this! And yes, you are correct. I messed up the parameters. Everything works fine now. Thank you!